# Switching MainActivity's tabs from a RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

Simple question: I have MainActivity with tabs in TabLayout and with a few fragments in the tabs. I'm able to select desired tab programatically from inside a fragment like this:

```
TabLayout tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(0);
tab.select();
```

But things get tricky when I want to do the same thing from a RecyclerView Adapter inside one of the fragments. The "getActivity" part is the problem. I was trying to pass FragmentActivity to the Adapter to use it instead like this:

`TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) fa.findViewById(R.id.tabs);`

But I get hit with NPE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved by simply pulling instance from the fragment and getting activity from that instance:

```
TabLayout tabs = FragmentSets.getInstance().getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```